# SSIS Substring, Findstring, and trying to separate a full name column into two columns

Tags: ssis

I have a Derived Column task set up in SSIS to split a FullName column into FirstName and LastName columns.  The data comes in from a flat file (delimited text file, separated by commas) and looks like this:

```
|FullName|
|Lastname, Firstname Middlename|
```

Here is how I am trying to get the data to show up  IMPORTANT NOTE - Not all records have a middle name:

```
|FirstName|LastName|
|Firstname M|Lastname|
```

The LastName column was easy to populate using Substring and Findstring appropriately.  My issue now is pulling in the the first name and first letter of the middle name into the FirstName column.  I wrote this:

```
SUBSTRING(Name, (FINDSTRING(FullName, ",", 1) + 1), (FINDSTRING(FullName, ",", 1) + 1))
```

Comment: ou probably meant to write `SUBSTRING(FullName, ...` instead of `SUBSTRING(Name, ...`.

Comment: @billinkc - Not entirely.  We are asking a very similar question but we desire two different results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SubString(
    Right(FullName, Len(FullName) - FindString(FullName, ",", 1)),
    1,
    FindString(Right(FullName, Len(FullName) - FindString(FullName, ",", 1)), " ", 1) > 0
    ?
    FindString(Right(FullName, Len(FullName) - FindString(FullName, ",", 1)), " ", 1) + 1
    :
    Len(Right(FullName, Len(FullName) - FindString(FullName, ",", 1)))
)
```

The `Right(FullName, Len(FullName) - FindString(FullName, ",", 1))` part appearing in the code several times extracts `Firstname Middlename`. Then the `Substring` around it cuts off after the initial of the middle name.

And to take care of the case that there may be no space in this `Firstname Middlename`, there is a condition as the last argument of `SubString` which either returns the length of `Firstname M`, or the length of the whole string, in which case `SubString` returns the whole string.

I hope I got all positions correct, and not one off to the left or right.

Comment: This will return `irstName MiddleName`.

Comment: @RonS I edited my answer to correct it.

Comment: @FrankPI Gorgeous!  That is exactly what I was looking for.  I was trying to figure this one out after your first example, but I kept getting lost in all the parenthesis.  Long day!

Comment: Before I accept this, one quick question - how could I handle a situation in which there are no middle names?

Comment: @RonS I took care of that as well in my new edit. However, the code gets longer and longer. And it does not take care of the case that there is no comma in `FullName`, or no space after the comma. But these cases are left as an exercise to the reader...